# Send Dockerfile contents to Docker Daemon API

Tags: docker, docker-image

I am viewing the documentation for [building an image via the Docker API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.30/#operation/ImageBuild) and the documentation states that the `Dockerfile` parameter is a

> Path within the build context to the Dockerfile. This is ignored if remote is specified and points to an external Dockerfile.

Which I 100% understand.  But I have occasionally had the use case come up where someone would want to send the contents of the Dockerfile itself (rather than the path to the file) to the Docker `/build` endpoint to build an image.  Is this possible?

Comment: You always have to POST the tar file of the build context as the message body; the path query parameter is a path within that tar file.  If you really had an image that could be built from a bare `Dockerfile`, just make that the only thing in the tar file.

Comment: ah okay I understand, thank you for clarifying